# bind9 response over network card has delay

Tags: bind

Im install bind9.8  cache recursion in ubuntu16.04 
whet i dig @127.0.0.1 google.com it answer quickly

```
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 08 23:06:50 IRST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 191
```

when query over network its very slow

```
dig @172.16.133.100 google.com
;; Query time: 3597 msec
;; SERVER: 172.16.133.100#53(172.16.133.100)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 08 23:08:42 IRST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 191
```

How can i troublshooting this delay

Answer (score 0):

First you do not compare two equivalent things, in first case you query nameserver `127.0.0.1` and in second case it is `172.16.133.100`

You should have a look at your log files, examine the `forward` directives you have in your bind configuration, and if not sufficient you will need to sniff your network to see what happens with your DNS packets.

Comment: my problem is load over network and i don no howto resolve and toubleshoot. Service is ok and response fast locally but over network is too slow.

Comment: Please read my answer for troubleshooting tips.